# Making a ListVectorPlot3D from data in an external file

Tags: plotting, import, vector

I have a .dat file with six columns: `{x y z vx vy vz}`, where x, y, z are space coordinates and vx, vy, vz are the vector components.

How can I use this file to get a `ListVectorPlot3D` image? Because I tried to arrange the data as `{{x,y,z}, {vx,vy,vz}}` and *Mathematica* still gives me an error message:

> ListVectorPlot3D::vfldata ... is not a valid vector field dataset or a valid list of datasets.

I haven't found many related question about this, just one about using `Graphics` and drawing each vector, but I think it would be simpler to use `ListVectorPlot`.

Comment: Can you upload a sample of you data please?

Comment: Ok, here is a sample: [link](http://pastebin.com/VByC3ZEg)

Comment: How very odd... all your data points lie in a plane?

Comment: Yes, it's a 2D plane and I wanted 3D vectors, so I put z=0 for all the vectors

Comment: This is a bit weird David. I don't have time to poke around much more - I'm sure someone here knows what's happening there

Comment: Ok :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I imported your data

```
data = Import["http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=VByC3ZEg", "Table"];
```

and transformed it into a vector field, deleting duplicated entries:

```
vecdata = Partition[#, 3] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[data];
```

As noted in a comment, the base points all lie in the xy-plane (and the z-components of the vectors are nearly the same):

```
vecdata[[All, 1, 3]] // Union
```

> ```
> {0.}
> ```

```
vecdata[[All, 2, 3]] // Union
```

> ```
> {-1., -0.998891, -0.995571, -0.990063, -0.982406}
> ```

Since the points lie in a plane, `ListVectorPlot3D` cannot interpolate a vector field over a region in space and plot it.  I can suggest two different visualizations, plotting the vectors themselves (as you considered) and projecting the vectors onto the plane and plotting that field.

The 3D vectors:

```
Graphics3D[{ColorData[1][1], Arrowheads[Medium], Arrow[{First@#, Total@#}] & /@ vecdata}]
```

[image: 3D plot of vectors]

2D `ListVectorPlot`:

```
ListVectorPlot[Map[Most, vecdata, {2}]]
```

[image: 2D ListVectorPlot]

Comment: Thanks! I've learned a lot with your answer. When I plot with all my data, the box is too small in height. Is there a way to get a larger box in Graphics3D?

Comment: @DavidWinchester Set [`BoxRatios -> {1,1,1}`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BoxRatios.html) or whatever relative sizes you want.  Thank you, too.