# How to visualize the vorticity of a 3D velocity field?

Tags: graphics3d, vector-calculus, streams, fluid-dynamics

I sample a snapshot from a system with 50 particles including their position and instant velocities.

The snapshot is a list of 3 position and 3 velocities values per particle.  i.e. 50 lines each of which is comprised of $(x,y,z,\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z})$ (AKA phase space coordinates).

My data set's layout is similar to the one used in [Making a ListVectorPlot3D from data in an external file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26519/making-a-listvectorplot3d-from-data-in-an-external-file), hence it is, basically, a velocity field in 3D.

I want to calculate and plot the following properties of the dynamics: [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)), [div](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence), [stream of the fluid in 3D](https://www.quora.com/Fluid-Mechanics-What-is-the-velocity-stream-function-in-a-flow-process), [vorticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity).

How can I visualize those attributes of the velocity field in 3D? Something like this in 3D would be great:

[image]

I have only a 2D presentation:

In addition I think that calculating and to visualize the [Covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) or correlation between the pairwise particles could be interesting too.

---

```
data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/6Werdnpf"];
vecdata = Partition[#, 3] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[data];
Graphics3D[{ColorData[1][1], Arrowheads[Medium], Arrow[{First@#, Total@#}] & /@ vecdata}]
ListVectorPlot[Map[Most, vecdata, {2}]]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of the type of plot you are trying to generate?

Comment: @C.E. frankly speaking, I am open to hear any suggestion. I want to plot the vortex lines in 3D, the vorticity, the div, or any other CFD property of the velocity field. Or any visualization of the 6D phase space or its subspaces.

Comment: ok, it's a legitimate question but if it doesn't receive any answers and you still want something then I would recommend to rewrite it as a question purely about *Mathematica*, along the lines of "I have this data. I want to make this type of plot. How do I do it in *Mathematica*?"

Comment: @C.E. no problem, thank you. I just don't want to limit people's creativity by giving such a reference plot.

Comment: **Please STOP editing the title to bump up the question on the homepage.** This question doesn't need 15 revisions... This question [was cross-posted on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41948428) as a MATLAB question, which makes me agree with C. E. that this is a physics/I-need-this-done-somehow question masquerading as a _Mathematica_ question. I would be inclined to close it as Off-topic: Out of Scope.

Comment: @R.M, It is purely a mathematica question in which I try to plot the vorticity of a vector field. Both this and the [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948428/how-to-analyze-and-visualize-a-3d-velocity-field-flow) are related though by the fact that I am trying to plot the same data set.

Comment: "What is the best way to visualize those attributes of the velocity field?" - is not purely Mathematica question. "I want to show X by doing SMTH but I failed to find appropriate function for that" - this would be. But first you need to know what exactly do you want to do.

Comment: @Kuba actually I am trying to plot the tube and stream lines, but I am not sure if it's the best practice. I could rephrase the question, though I don't want to limit people's creativity

Comment: @0x90 I understad, that is nice. Unfortunately this kind of creativity is off topic here :) unless you want them to get creative in what way they pick to do something specific.

Comment: @Kuba ok I focused my question in 3D presentations.

Comment: @0x90 that is not narrow enough, take a look at: [help/do-not-ask](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Kuba I want something like that https://cdn.comsol.com/wordpress/2014/12/Streamlines-dense.png

Comment: @0x90 and which field is visualized by what on that image. What have your tried?