# plotting a 3d vector field from a list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have imported data to a list as below.

```
nn = Import["df.dat", "Table"];
```

nn is a 100 by 4 matrix which shows a 3D director field in 100 different points in x-y plane (the vectors are 3d, but their origins are in a 2D plane). To be more clear, $nn[[3, i]]$  shows the component of the vector originated at point 3 in the space. $i=1,2,3$ show the x,y,z component of the vector and i=4 shows the length of the vector.

Also, these 100 points in the 2D plane are arranged on a 10 by 10 square with equal distance.

I really appreciate it if someone can help me to visualize this vector field in an appropriate way.

Below is the first 5 lines of the df.dat file.

```
0.121963 -0.224769 0.966749 0.340097
0.095170 -0.243081 0.965326 0.340081
0.068667 -0.261505 0.962756 0.340071
0.042826 -0.279722 0.959125 0.340065
0.017990 -0.297426 0.954575 0.340059
```

The first line corresponds to the point (x,y)=(0,0), the second point to the point (x,y)=(1,0) and so on. The 12th point corresponds to (x,y)=(2,1), the 14th point to (x,y)=(3,1) and so on.

Comment: Please give a minimal example of your df.dat.

Comment: did you see this? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26523/1089

Comment: @cvgmt I don't know how to upload it here.

Comment: Just post some part of your data as code.

Comment: added now. @cvgmt

Comment: @cvgmt I have also added how positions are related to the matrix nn.

Comment: @chris I saw that, but it does not solve my problem as the origin of vectors in my case is specified by the number of rows of data.

Comment: user258046, you could upload the data to pastebin & share it here. Also, have you seen [`ResourceFunction[“PlotVector3D”]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotVector3D)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example, that assumes that the vectors on the grid are numbered from 1 to 100:

```
vecs = Table[{1, 1, 1} i/10, {i, 100}];
origins = Flatten[Table[{i, j, 0}, {i, 10}, {j, 10}], 1];
Graphics3D[Table[Arrow[{t = origins[[i]], t + vecs[[i]]}], {i, 100}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please use the matrix nn with its 4 columns in your answer  so that it becomes clear how your answer is related to the question?

Comment: If I understood your description right, then the 3 first columns give the vector and the fourth its length. In this case the fourth is superfluous because the length is already specified implicitly by the 3 first columns.

Comment: It is true. Could you please use the matrix nn in your answer? It is not clear how your solution matches with nn with its first 3 colomns and 100 rows.

Comment: The vectors are numbered: 1..10 for origins {x,y}={1,1}..{1,10}, 11..20 for origins {2,1}.{2,10} e.t.c

Comment: I am confused by your solution. I don't see how it is related to the question as I do not see any nn matrix in your solution.

Comment: @user258046 if you aren’t satisfied by the answer, it’s better to refrain from accepting it & allow for others to provide answers for you to choose from.

Comment: @CATrevillian i'M NOT FULLY SATISFIED SINCE THE PRESENTATION IS NOT GOOD. But its OK otherwise.